# How to get the QueryRenderer to propagate parent prop changes?

Tags: reactjs, relayjs, relay, relaymodern

Using Relay Modern v.1.4.1, consider the following `List` component.

It takes two props `foo` and `bar` and renders a `Table` component with these props and the result of the GraphQL query:

```
class List extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // I accept this.props.foo and this.props.bar
    this.renderQuery = this.renderQuery.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    return <QueryRenderer
      environment={this.props.relayEnvironment}
      query={SomeQuery}
      variables={{
        count: 20,
      }}
      render={this.renderQuery}
    />;
  }

  renderQuery(readyState) {
    console.log("List component props:");
    console.log(this.props);
    return <Table 
      foo={this.props.foo} bar={this.props.bar} 
      data={readyState.data}
    />
  }

}
```

Now, for the initial rendering of the `Table` component `foo` and `bar` are set correctly, however if `foo` or `bar` change afterwards the new values are not propagated to the `Table` component because of the `QueryRenderer`.

Since the `QueryRenderer` only re-renders if the `variables` for `SomeQuery` change the `renderQuery` method is not triggered because the `QueryRenderer` does not see a need for it, so the `Table` component stays with the old prop values.

Since passing down props to children is a very common task the fact that the `QueryRenderer` is oblivious to the parent's prop changes poses quite a problem. I've been wondering what the solution for this might be and came up with some options:

1. Use [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to bypass this behaviour. However it is generally discouraged to use Context unless you have good reasons for it + it feels like a dirty hack to circumvent the issue.
2. Force the `QueryRenderer` to re-render with the same `readyState` as before. This could perhaps be realized using `refs` but you would need to check when to re-render by yourself.
3. Somehow make the `QueryRenderer` care about my props. This is obviously the right way but I didn't find anything in the documentation that allows this, so I would need to do something like creating a Higher Order Component from the `QueryRenderer` or a subclass of it that implements this behavious.

Ideally I would like to have a native way to make the `QueryRenderer` look at prop changes, something like

```
<QueryRenderer
  environment={this.props.relayEnvironment}
  query={SomeQuery}
  variables={{
    count: 20,
  }}
  render={this.renderQuery}
  propagateProps={this.props}
/>
```

or

```
<QueryRenderer
  environment={this.props.relayEnvironment}
  query={SomeQuery}
  variables={{
    count: 20,
  }}
  render={this.renderQuery}
  {...this.props}
/>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove your Class component and change the above code to:

```
const List = (parentProps) => (
  <QueryRenderer
    environment={parentProps.relayEnvironment}
    query={SomeQuery}
    variables={{
      count: 20,
    }}
    render={({ props }) => (
      <Table 
        foo={this.parentProps.foo} bar={this.parentProps.bar} 
        data={props.data}
      />
    )}
  />
)
```

QueryRenderer is already a React Component in itself and you normally do not have to wrap it in a class Component render.

List is now a Pure function component and when it receives new props (parentProps) it will re-render, hence Table with be re-rendered